# Type '(event: DragEvent<any>) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: DragEvent<HTMLHeadingElement>) => void'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, draggable, react-beautiful-dnd

I've been using react-beautiful-dnd for a while in my project, but recently I'm getting this following error

> Type '`{ children: string; className: string; style: { whiteSpace: "nowrap"; textOverflow: string; width: string; }; } | { children: string; onMouseDown: (event: MouseEvent<any, MouseEvent>) => void; ... 10 more ...; style: { ...; }; }`' is not assignable to type '`DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>, HTMLHeadingElement>`'.
>
>  
> Type '`{ children: string; onMouseDown: (event: MouseEvent<any, MouseEvent>) => void; onKeyDown: (event: KeyboardEvent<any>) => void; onTouchStart: (event: TouchEvent<any>) => void; onTouchMove: (event: TouchEvent<...>) => void; ... 7 more ...; style: { ...; }; }`' is not assignable to type '`DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>, HTMLHeadingElement>`'. 
>  
> Type '`{ children: string; onMouseDown: (event: MouseEvent<any, MouseEvent>) => void; onKeyDown: (event: KeyboardEvent<any>) => void; onTouchStart: (event: TouchEvent<any>) => void; onTouchMove: (event: TouchEvent<...>) => void; ... 7 more ...; style: { ...; }; }`' is not assignable to type '`HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>`'. 
>  
> Types of property 'onDragStart' are incompatible. 
> Type '`(event: DragEvent<any>) => void`' is not assignable to type '`(event: DragEvent<HTMLHeadingElement>) => void`'. 
> Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible. 
> Type '`DragEvent<HTMLHeadingElement>`' is missing the following properties from type '`DragEvent<any>`': detail, view  TS2322

My Component structure is like this

```
<>
  <Draggable
    draggableId={props.column._id ? props.column._id.toString() : "0"}
    index={props.index}
  >
    {(provided) => (
      <div
        className="dib h-100 w-23-l w-50-m"
        style={{ minWidth: "270px" }}
        {...provided.draggableProps}
        ref={provided.innerRef}
      >
        <div className="flex flex-column h-100 pr3 w-100">
          <div className="w-100">
            <div className="flex pb1 w-100">
              <h3
                className="pl1 overflow-hidden ma0 fw6 flex-grow-1 ws-normal ws-break pv1"
                style={{
                  whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                  textOverflow: "ellipsis",
                  width: "220px",
                }}
                {...provided.dragHandleProps}
              >
                {props.column.name}
              </h3>
```

At first I thought this was an issue with the package, but it was working fine all along and now it's throwing me this error. Any idea how I can solve this one?

Comment: You haven't posted your full relevant code. Where are you setting `onDragStart`? Where is the rest of your JSX/TSX/HTML?

Comment: @Dai I think onDragStart is part of `provided.dragHandleProps` or `provided.draggableProps`

Comment: Can you check if you are using different versions of react with `npm list react`?

Comment: @diedu I'm using react@16.14.0

Comment: @dai the code is pretty long, so I posted only the relevant part, should I post the full code?

Comment: did you check all other dependencies are also using the same react version? `npm list react` should show only 16.14.0 entries